# How do I fix the Nightingale Hood glitch where it turns white instead of its normal black color?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

At random times when I have the [Nightingale Hood](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Nightingale_Hood) equipped it appears to turn white instead of its normal black coloring.  This does seem to happen quite a few times at the [Ragged Flagon](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Ragged_Flagon).  Is there any way to fix this?

I am playing Skyrim on the PS3.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Could you please be more specific with your question, or upload a screenshot?

Comment: So... what exactly is the issue? Is white not a good colour or...?

Comment: no its just annoys me when something isnt as it is supposed to be and it kinda clashes with the rest of the armor witch bugs me quite a bit

Comment: @Ysmir-Einarr2836 So WHAT IS IT supposed to be? That's what I was getting at. You gave the actual result, but not the EXPECTED result. So people have no idea what your problem is.

Comment: @deutschZuid you edited out the expected result (the normal color is black).  You also removed the location where it seems to occur more often (the raggon flagon [sp?]).  It seems especially harsh to castigate someone for leaving out information that you removed.

Comment: @Brythan I didn't actually. What do I gain from doing that? It's possible that he edited the question at the same as I did and my save overwrote his. There is no edit conflict control on SE I believe.

Comment: @deutschZuid  I would have thought that that would have shown up in the edit history.  Maybe you accidentally selected a whole line rather than something smaller when editing?  It's hard to see what changes have been made during editing.  I find that annoying myself.

Comment: @Brythan I don't think changes show up if they are made immediately to your last change. Maybe five minutes? Not quite sure.

Answer (score 3):

OK, so it seems like this is a problem with the shaders after a patch some time ago. After browsing several forums, it seems like the only solution (someone says it's permanent and someone says it's temporary) is to put the hood on a mannequin in a house, leave the house and restart you game. When you go back in it should be fixed!

Sources:
[gamefaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615804-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/61942997)
[theskyrimblog](http://theskyrimblog.ning.com/profiles/status/show?id=6452022%3AStatus%3A840501)

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this issue of the hood glitching on my system. You do not need a mannequin to fix this issue. Simply remove the nightingale hood your character is wearing. Keep it in your inventory and save your game. Shut off your system completely after saving and exiting the game. Turn your system back on after it shuts off completely. Restart your game from the save point and put the hood on. The hood should appear black again when you equip it.

Answer (score 0):

I just switch between armors. I don't know if it helps or not but I exchanged my Nightingale armor for a Hooded Thalmor robe and Thalmor gloves and boots. Keep in mind this usually doesn't work but it worked a few times for me. I don't think it has to be Thalmor armor though...

Comment: This may have been something you did, but doesn't address the OP's question about resolving a graphical glitch. (Unless you mean switching armors fixes the glitch, then please rephrase your answer accordingly.) Welcome to Arqade.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this too, The mannequin helps, go to your house, equip it on a mannequin, save, quit, load again. It should be fine. For me sometimes this happens in Falmer like caves, and you'll notice the Charus turn white, along with glowing mushrooms that seem to glow brighter, even the chests (That I think are made from the abdomen or body of a charus) turn this white too. I've tried just restarting when this happens IN THESE TYPES OF CAVES, and it worked, otherwise just restarting idk. Oh and take note, It refused to work the first 3-4 times I tried it on the mannequin in the  Markarth house that you buy. I haven't tried it since but my guess is that it doesn't work. This glitch bothers the hell out of me and I don't know why lol

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this has been a problem for many Skyrim players and this solution will usually work. On occasion the Nightingale hood will still be white but I suggest trying again. What you want to do is go to one of your Homes with a Mannequin in it, place the Nightingale hood on the Mannequin, save and then quit your game then shut down your system. Go back on and your hood will most likely be the "forged midnight" the guards refer to it as.

-An Anonymous User

Answer (score 0):

I've found something that works for me since I find turning off the system is a little time consuming. Take off the nightingale hood and leave it in ur inventory. Then fast travel away, when u get to where u traveled to put the hood back on. It fixed the problem of the white color for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just recently started having this very same issue every now and then which is a real bummer as I wear the Nightengale armor set almost always unless I am in some heavy combat.

I have found that selecting the Nightengale hood in my opened inventory and clicking it on and off in rapid succession (equipping-unequipping quickly) sometimes helps fix the problem.